# Access VBA Dmin and Dmax on comma seperated decimals

Tags: function, ms-access, vba, locale

My system is using , **`as decimal seperator and .`** as thousands.

When i use the Dmin and Dmax functions in VBA, i get the error:

```
run-time error 3075 syntax error (comma)
```

While running this:-

```
UpperPower = DMin("Column2", "t_table", "Column2" & ">=" & RatedPower)
```

Where `RatedPower` is a function variable declared `Public RatedPower As Double`.
The function is declared `double` as well.

Everything else works fine with the comma being the decimal seperator.

I have looked into the replace function but I am not sure how to use it in the Dmin function...

What can i do?

Best Regards, Emil.

Comment: What is RatedPower? Manual Entry? If so what is it declared as?

Comment: Edited in the question!

Comment: Could you not change the separators in your regional settings?

Comment: No i can chose only to use either English (Standard) or danish. It was danish, but i changed to english. Does not help. Excel uses . as seperator.

Comment: Check out MS website on this : http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/change-the-separator-for-thousands-and-decimals-HP003089676.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but that seems to be for 2003. I have 2010 :( It does not have that path...

Comment: A collegue found the solution. It had to be changed in Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region

Then i could pick the general seperator as . That works fine but it would still be an issue when the databased is opened on another computer. So i am still looking for a solution to the original question.

Comment: Awesome. Could you add it the answer? So everyone could benefit from that?

Comment: Ye i just accidently hit enter :D

Comment: Okay, now my charts cant figure it out... They dont see the decimal seperator... Wtf...

Comment: Does Column1 stores decimal values or string?

Comment: All values are Doubles!

Comment: I have added additional question, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861530/ms-access-chart-not-recognizing-decimal-seperator

 If you think you can help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
UpperPower = DMin("Column2", "t_table", "Column2 >= " & Replace(RatedPower, ",", "."))
```

Since the first argument to Replace() must be a string, RatedPower is implicitly converted to a string using the local decimal separator (if non-integer) and no thousands separators.

This code is foolproof, in that it works regardless if the local decimal separator is "." or ","

Comment: I will try that!
Will UpperPower be returned as a string then, or as a double?

Comment: @emil it will be returned as Column2's data type in the table, i.e. as Double. To prove this to yourself, enter this command in the Debug window: `?typename(dmin("Column 2","t_table"))`

Comment: That totally worked out great. Thank you very much Tom!