# MS Access chart not recognizing decimal seperator

Tags: ms-access, charts, ms-access-2010

I have the following table and chart. The decimal . is not recognized, but why?

What am I doing wrong? (Look at the Y scale in the chart)

And this is a problem because some values has 3 digits ans some has 4. And it is generated with the round function Round(Number,3) ...

[image: Table]
[image: Criteria]
[image: Chart]

Is this a rookie mistake?

Best regards, Emil.

Comment: Have you checked the properties of your Y-axis? There is a setting in here to control the unit shown. If I remember correctly, you can set it to things like hundredths, millions, etc.

Comment: How did you create the chart?

Comment: Note the rightmost three blue bars. The tallest represents 8.0249 while the shorter ones represent larger numbers 11.666 and 43.239. So it isn't a Y-axis scaling problem. Based on your other post I think this might be a locale-related problem, and the decimal point is being interpreted (and ignored) as a thousands-separator. Also, is it possible you used Round(n,4)?

Comment: Hi Tom, i will try your replace comma suggestion and get back to you. I know it is not a scaling problem, as you correctly pointed out. And yes, it is a problem that for example 11,32 and 11,321 are read as 1132 and 11321 - That gives quite a difference ;) It might be a local problem because of the dot and comma mixings... However, i find it very strange that the chart can not read it, but the tables can... Excel has no problems either.